# line before the async function is being called

Tags: node.js, express

so I am building some simple node projects and I am making some requests using [GOT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) as the original requests lib for node is discontinued, but this weird thing keeps happening and calls anything before the async function as a function.

below is the code I am running

```
let express = require("express")
let app = express()
let bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const got = require('got');
app.set("view engine", "ejs")


app.get("/search", function(req, res){
    let query = req.query.pesq
    let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb"
    (async () => {
        try {
            const response = got(url);
            data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log("fine here")
            res.render("search", {data: data})
            //=> '<!doctype html> ...'
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.code);
            //=> 'Internal server error ...'
        }
    })
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!")
})
```

And this is the error I get from it

```
TypeError: "&apikey=thewdb" is not a function
at /workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/index.js:11:2
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

I am trying to find out why the line before the async function is being called as a function as the error shows. I tried adding a `console.log("check")` after the `let url` and I got another error:

```
TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function
at /workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/index.js:12:2
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/Bootcamp/MoviaApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

However I have no idea why it is having this weird behavior of calling the line before, probably it is something very simple but I can't find out. sorry if this question has already been answered but I can't find an answer.

Update: added the `await` before the `got(url)` function and still returns the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the string "&apikey=thewdb" as a function.

Let's rearrange your code a bit to clearly see this:

```
let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb"
(async () => { ...
```

is the same as

```
let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb"(async () => ...
```

Let's rewrite that to be really obvious:

```
let callback = async () => {
    try {
        const response = got(url);
        data = JSON.parse(response.body);
        console.log("fine here")
        res.render("search", {data: data})
        //=> '<!doctype html> ...'
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.code);
        //=> 'Internal server error ...'
    }
}

let string = "&apikey=thewdb";

let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=";
url = url + query;
url = url + string(callback); // you are calling the string as a function
```

Obviously `"&apikey=thewdb"` is not a function so the interpreter complains that `"&apikey=thewdb"` is not a function.

#### DO NOT simply leave out semicolons!

If you don't like semicolons then you **must** use [standard.js](https://standardjs.com/) rules. You cannot simply make up your own rules otherwise you will encounter bugs such as this.

If you don't like standard.js then you **must** use semicolons.

There is no alternative choice.

Remember, in javascript you can legally call a function like this:

```
function foo () {
    console.log('foo is called');
}

foo

(
) // foo is called
```

Comment: ooh now I see, I thougth using semicolons was not needed anymore so I left all my code without semicolons. well, I've done everything until here without semicolons so i guess i'll have to get used to writing them again. thanks friend

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call your async function and forgot the `await` when making the call:

```
let express = require("express")
let app = express()
let bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const got = require('got');
app.set("view engine", "ejs")


app.get("/search", function(req, res){
    let query = req.query.pesq
    let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb"
    (async () => {
        try {
            const response = await got(url);
            data = JSON.parse(response.body);
            console.log("fine here")
            res.render("search", {data: data})
            //=> '<!doctype html> ...'
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.code);
            //=> 'Internal server error ...'
        }
    })()
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!")
})
```

Comment: just added the await before the got(url) , still getting the same result. i even tried copying your entire code but no success

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting a ";" at the end of

```
let url = ("https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb")
```

so it became

```
    let url = ("https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb");
```

and worked fine, probably something to do with the express library or the Goorm IDE itself but it is weird anyways.

Comment: It's nothing to do with express. It's basic javascript syntax. See my answer